# Inherit from base UserControl

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, user-controls

I have several `user controls` that have similar functionality, so I was thinking about moving all these methods to a `BaseUserControl class`, and make all the `user controls` inherit from it.

However, when I do so, I get this compliler warning:

```
Base class BaseUserControl  specified for class UserControl1 cannot be different from the base class System.Windows.Forms.UserControl of one of its other partial types
```

I know I'm getting this warning because when I create the `BaseUserControl`, the autogenerated code in its designer adds an inheritance to `System.Windows.Forms.UserControl`.

So,

```
 1. how can I inherit from an `UserControl` in `VB.NET`?

 2.Is it possible? If not, how could I avoid code repetition in my case?
```

Thanks!

Comment: You'd want your `BaseUserControl` class to inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.UserControl`, and in the `BaseUserControl .designer.vb` it should be the same. Then, for your controls that inherit `BaseUserControl`, make sure their `CustomControl.designer.vb` is set to Inherit from `BaseUserControl`.